# Error while installation of CHMSee

Tags: chmsee

I have recently migrated from Windows to Ubuntu.

My current locale shows below output:

```
    cha@COMPUTER:~$ locale
    LANG=en_IN
    LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
    LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
    LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
    LC_TIME="en_IN"
    LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
    LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
    LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
    LC_PAPER="en_IN"
    LC_NAME="en_IN"
    LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
    LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
    LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
    LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
    LC_ALL=
```

When I am trying to install CHMSee (or any other Application) using Software Center, I am getting below error.

```
    installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
    perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
        are supported and installed on your system.
    perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
    perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
        are supported and installed on your system.
    perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
    perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
        are supported and installed on your system.
    perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
    perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
        are supported and installed on your system.
    perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    Selecting previously unselected package libchm1.
    (Reading database ... 
    (Reading database ... 5%
    (Reading database ... 10%
    (Reading database ... 15%
    (Reading database ... 20%
    (Reading database ... 25%
    (Reading database ... 30%
    (Reading database ... 35%
    (Reading database ... 40%
    (Reading database ... 45%
    (Reading database ... 50%
    (Reading database ... 55%
    (Reading database ... 60%
    (Reading database ... 65%
    (Reading database ... 70%
    (Reading database ... 75%
    (Reading database ... 80%
    (Reading database ... 85%
    (Reading database ... 90%
    (Reading database ... 95%
    (Reading database ... 100%
    (Reading database ... 207053 files and directories currently installed.)
    Unpacking libchm1 (from .../libchm1_2%3a0.40a-1_i386.deb) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0.
    Unpacking libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 (from .../libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_1.8.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libwebkitgtk-1.0-common.
    Unpacking libwebkitgtk-1.0-common (from .../libwebkitgtk-1.0-common_1.8.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0.
    Unpacking libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 (from .../libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_1.8.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
    Selecting previously unselected package chmsee.
    Unpacking chmsee (from .../chmsee_1.3.0-2ubuntu2_i386.deb) ...
    Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
    Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
    Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
    Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
    Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
    Processing triggers for man-db ...
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    Setting up qmail (1.06-4) ...

    The hostname -f command returned: $1

    Your system needs to have a fully qualified domain name (fqdn) in
    order to install the var-qmail packages.

    Installation aborted.

    dpkg: error processing qmail (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qmail-run:
     qmail-run depends on qmail (>= 1.06-2.1); however:
      Package qmail is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing qmail-run (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
    Setting up libchm1 (2:0.40a-1) ...
    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
    Setting up libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 (1.8.0-0ubuntu2) ...
    Setting up libwebkitgtk-1.0-common (1.8.0-0ubuntu2) ...
    Setting up libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 (1.8.0-0ubuntu2) ...
    Setting up chmsee (1.3.0-2ubuntu2) ...
    Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
    ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     qmail
     qmail-run
    Error in function: 
    SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
    Setting up qmail (1.06-4) ...

    The hostname -f command returned: $1

    Your system needs to have a fully qualified domain name (fqdn) in
    order to install the var-qmail packages.

    Installation aborted.

    dpkg: error processing qmail (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qmail-run:
     qmail-run depends on qmail (>= 1.06-2.1); however:
      Package qmail is not configured yet.
    dpkg: error processing qmail-run (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Can someone please help me in resolving this issue? The elaboration would be most appreciated since I am very new to this.

Comment: Does `hostname -f` return `$1`? Seems like an odd thing to return but that might be your problem.

Comment: no it doesn't.'cha@COMPUTER:~$ hostname -f
COMPUTER'

Comment: Guys Please help. I am totally stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several problems here, but the main thing is probably the locale settings which I mention in my third point:

1)  You could first try to remove the program (`qmail`) that seems to be causing the problems (and preventing you installing anything else) by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove qmail
```

Or if you want to keep it and try to configure it (and anything else), run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

We cannot use `dpkg-reconfigure` until the package is actually configured in the first place.

Now please try to run `sudo apt-get update`.

2) Even though your error messages include something about your hostname, this is probably a red herring, as you have discussed in the comments. Nevertheless, you could still check that the output of `cat /etc/hostname` and the hostname at the top of `/etc/hosts` are the same.

3) Now, your main problem is probably to do with your locale settings, even though the output of `locale` doesn't look particularly amiss. However, the exact errors generated by your problem have occurred several times on Ubuntuforums. The [general advice](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1346581) is to run `locale-gen` and feed it with your particular settings; for example, in your case you could run:

```
sudo locale-gen en.IN
```

You might also need to add `en_IN.ISO8859-1` or `en_IN.UTF-8`, depending on how you want your encoding settings specified. The advice in the [article here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1346581) is quite useful and could be further modified to suit your needs if necessary. After running `locale-gen`, it is also useful to run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

If that does not solve the issue, there is further documentation on locales at [the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale). However, the solution should be to do with locales as it appears to be a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/hosts file to change

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 desktop
```

to

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 desktop.your.domain desktop
```

Example: with my machine

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 vnpt
```

to

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 vnpt.vnpt-domain vnpt
```

After that you can install qmail.